# sudo apt-get update is taking a long time after upgrading software from software center in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, update-manager

```
tejesh@tejesh-Inspiron-3542:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http:// extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http:// dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http:// dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http:// extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http:// archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http:// dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http:// extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http:// dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http:// archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Sources                        
Hit http:// dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http:// extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http:// archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http:// extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http:// archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http:// extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http:// archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http:// dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN                         
Ign http:// dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                   
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                         
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease   
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease   
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg 
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http:// extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg 
Ign http:// extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg 
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages             
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg 
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_IN                     
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Err http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                       
Hit http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Ign http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                               
Get:1 http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [237 kB]
Get:2 http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [140 kB]       
Get:3 http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [5,144 B]    
Get:4 http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [627 kB]  
Get:5 http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15.4 kB]
Get:6 http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [320 kB]
Get:7 http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [11.9 kB]
Get:8 http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [608 kB]     
Get:9 http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15.1 kB]
Get:10 http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [321 kB]
Get:11 http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [12.1 kB]
Get:12 http:// archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [304 kB]   
100% [Waiting for headers]
```

Comment: I have no idea what you point is here, all that show is `apt-get update` was not 100% successful ? You see the line `Err http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found` Remove this PPA from the software and updates app and update again

Comment: " Remove this PPA from the software and updates app and update again " What do you mean exactly by this?

Comment: Open the application `software and updates` from the dash (top left) and go to `other software` find the one called `http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages` click it, then click `remove`, now update again

Comment: It is not there in the list :(

Comment: That is not possible, it must be called some thing very close like `http:// ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main`

Comment: Tejesh, you need to be careful about how you ask questions here. Don't just post terminal output. Ask your question as well! In any case, the output you posted is not complete.

Comment: @markkirby I have tried but even then I am able able to find any option close to it

Comment: By the way the apt-get update process has been finished and the last few lines are as follows:

Fetched 15.2 MB in 47min 46s (5,304 B/s)                                       
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
tejesh@tejesh-Inspiron-3542:~$

Comment: What shall I do next ?

Comment: Do you see those PPA in you software sources ? ppa.launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main or ppa.launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main

Comment: Yes these two PPA are present in the software sources

I have unticked them

Comment: Remove them they dont exist any more, update again

Comment: Thank you so much Mark Kirby for giving your time. 
apt-get update worked as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apt-get update` process had been finished and the last few lines were as follows:

```
Fetched 15.2 MB in 47min 46s (5,304 B/s) 

W: Failed to fetch ppa .launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/… 404 Not Found 

W: Failed to fetch ppa .launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/… 404 Not Found 

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. 
tejesh@tejesh-Inspiron-3542:~$
```

When you get this open the application software and updates and from the others tab remove this from the list:

```
ppa .launchpad.net/picaso/octave/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main
```